# count non zero column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

[image: have]

[image: Want]

In a pandas dataframe,
I need a Count column that counts non zero occurrences

help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
df['Count'] = df.filter(regex='col\d').ne(0).sum(axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

  group_col  col1  col2  col3  Count
0    group1    23     0    32      2
1    group2     1     1    38      3
2    group3     0     9    97      2
```